# Proper way of creating a video streaming server

Tags: python, django, video-streaming

I am working with the Django framework and I need to create a video streaming server, this is when one user records a video and we broadcast it to thousands of other users through the server. At one moment there can be many broadcasts at once, which will be on different URLs. I'm not sure that Django is the right tool for this kind of work, so I'm leaning towards the socket library in the Python programming language, as it can use the UDP protocol and I can implement everything asynchronously and connect to the project Django-ORM. Another option is Fast API, it is asynchronous, but if I'm not mistaken it works only with TCP, which is not the best option for streaming. I will have only a few days to implement the project, and it will be necessary to start soon, unfortunately, I will not have time for experiments.

Can anybody tell me if I am moving in the right direction? Or should I use other tools for this?

Answer (score 2):

> I will have only a few days to implement the project, and it will be necessary to start soon, unfortunately, I will not have time for experiments.

Please excuse my bluntness, but it needs to be said that you do not have time to build something like this in a few days.  Frankly, based on your questions, you should spend some months studying up on how all of this works.

You also need to better define your scope.  It isn't clear what your latency requirements are, client compatibility, budget, are we even talking live or pre-recorded?

You should integrate with an existing full-service provider that can meet your needs, such as Vimeo.

In the meantime, I will address some of your comments.

> I am working with the Django framework

Not relevant.  Whatever you use for your web application doesn't influence what you use for streaming.

> this is when one user records a video and we broadcast it to thousands of other users through the server

Live?  Or actually pre-recorded?  If it's pre-recorded, you can use just regular HTTP file/blob CDNs.  If it's live, you can still use those CDNs if you use a segmented streaming method like HLS or DASH, but those come with added latency.

> so I'm leaning towards the socket library in the Python programming language

You really want to re-invent an ingest protocol?  I'd not recommend it.  It's not necessary at all.

> as it can use the UDP protocol and I can implement everything asynchronously and connect to the project Django-ORM

What does your ORM have to do with it?  Nothing really.

> Another option is Fast API, it is asynchronous, but if I'm not mistaken it works only with TCP, which is not the best option for streaming.

This is nonsense.  Whomever told you this had good intent, but it's not an either/or situation.

You're streaming a source to thousands... that implies there is no realtime feedback loop the source, which means this isn't a low-latency application, which means that you have the opportunity to optimize for quality... and you should.  Therefore, if you lose a packet, you need to deal with that.  You can do that with UDP if the application layer handles it (see SRT), but otherwise there's **nothing wrong with TCP for streaming**.  Stop making assumptions.

> Can anybody tell me if I am moving in the right direction?

Your timeline dictates the size and scope of this project.  You *must* outsource this infrastructure part, and focus on building the product if you have any hope of success.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I really haven't experienced this direction. It must be a live video, where some users stream their live video, and thousands of others watch it. If TCP is not a bad option, I think I will try to use WebSockets for it. My employer doesn't want to use outside services and I should do everything myself.

Comment: @UserDev Your employer doesn't know what they're doing and this project is doomed to failure.  You cannot learn and do all of this in a couple days.  I am not trying to be defeatist, just realistic with you.